# Trello Account Confirmation results in internal server error

Tags: trello, email

When I click on the confirmation link I get an empty page with "Internal Server Error", tried different browsers.

And: There is absolutely not possibility to contact anybody on the whole Trello homepage!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, soon after I started using Trello. It turned out that they were having "a technical problem" - 15th Sept, on Twitter - and was fixed within an hour.

However, nothing on the [@TrelloApp twitter stream](https://twitter.com/#!/TrelloApp) suggests there have been any problems today.

Comment: I registered on the 15th and tried to activate my account each day and it never worked. I also got the confirmation mail again, but this link also didn't work.

Comment: Are there any non-alphanumeric characters in your name? See the "Deployed" section at the right of the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) - it says they've deployed a fix for [Can't create an account if your name has non-alphanumeric characters](https://trello.com/card/board/can-t-create-an-account-if-your-name-has-non-alphanumeric-characters/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e7065a10754b2e22200624f) - maybe that bug still existed when you registered?

Comment: I don't have non-alphanumeric characters in my name, but they fixed it now...

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed.